# How do I pipe into `code` to open a file in Visual Studio Code (VS Code)?

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code, unix, grep

I want to be able to pipe a file and also a file and line number into `code` such that Visual Studio Code (VS Code) opens the file in the current window. I know the command line options for `code` to do so, but I am not able to figure out how to pipe the output of some scripting that gives the filename to `code` in a way that works.

For example, maybe I'd like to pipe the output of `grep` and open the file in VS Code. The following command will print out the filename and line number.

```bash
grep --with-filename --line-number --recursive --max-count 1 --include \*.txt 'Test' . \
| cut --delimiter : --fields 1-2
```

will output something like `./filename.txt:47`. Now, `code`'s `--goto` option can handle this as expected if done like:

```bash
code --reuse-window --goto ./filename.txt:47
```

However, if I try to pipe into `code`, then VS Code just closes the current window and then opens a new blank window.

```bash
grep --with-filename --line-number --recursive --max-count 1 --include \*.txt 'Test' . \
| cut --delimiter : --fields 1-2 \
| code --reuse-window --goto
```

How do I make this work such that VS Code opens up the file at the line number in the current window? Am I doing something incorrectly with `bash` and the piping by incorrectly expecting this to just work? Or is this a `code` specific issue?

Answer (score 1):

To be clear, this is not piping anything *into* `code`. You just want to use the output of a command as an argument to it.

One thing to consider is how to deal with multiple files. If you want to open them all, I would use `xargs` with the `-n 1` option; the command below winds up running the `code` command once per identified file, eventually opening all the files in tabs of the same window:

```
grep -Hnrm 1 --include '*.txt' Test . |
  cut -d: -f1-2 |
  xargs -n 1 code --reuse-window --goto
```

If you only want to open the first file, you could just interject a `head`:

```
grep -Hnrm 1 --include '*.txt' Test . |
  cut -d: -f1-2 |
  head -n 1 |
  xargs code --reuse-window --goto
```

But in that case you don't really need `xargs` at all; you could use plain old command substitution:

```
code --reuse-window --goto \
  "$(grep -Hnrm 1 --include '*.txt' Test . |
     cut -d: -f1-2 | head -n 1)"
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use `xargs`.

```bash
grep --with-filename --line-number --recursive --max-count 1 --include \*.txt 'Test' . \
| cut --delimiter : --fields 1-2 \
| xargs --replace code --reuse-window --goto {}
```

The `--replace` will assume `{}` such that `xargs` will take the output of the pipe and place it where `{}` occurs in the following command.

I am interested in other ways to do this as well.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you just confusing the standard input stream with the commandline (/args)? you want `code --reuse-window --goto <output of command that produces thing>` (I.e. output of command is used as part of *commandline* (an argument)), but then you try to do `<command that produces thing> | code --reuse-window --goto` (I.e. piping output of command into the consumer's standard input stream).

You can substitute command outputs in commandlines in Bash by using `` `<command>` `` (enclose with backticks) or `$(<command>)` (also enclose with doublequotes if you want the output to be treated as a single commandline argument instead of being split by the field separator). Ex. `code --reuse-window --goto "$(grep --with-filename --line-number --recursive --max-count 1 --include \*.txt 'Test' . | cut --delimiter : --fields 1-2)"`.